# RamMap can't see what takes up memory

Tags: windows-7, memory

My pc is always using 2-3gb of ram in idle and I can't see why

I have been searching for the solution for some time with rammap, but it always ends up at look at the process private active usage, which is 1.7gb for nothing on my pc
but when I go to processes the private usage doesn't add up at all
same for poolmon

Tried adcleaner, malwarebytes, combofix, avast and ccleaner, still my ram is occupied

here is my rammap scan result:

http://www.file-upload.net/download-10058185/NICHT-PC.RMP.html

Answer (score 1):

RAMMAp shows it perfectly. 2GB are used by processes:

[image]

When you look into the process tab, I see several chrome.exe instances:

[image]

So Windows uses 3GB and the rest over 4GB contains preloaded data from [Superfetch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.vistakernel.aspx) (Cache) to improve performance when starting new programs.

Comment: so this was all just me not knowing how pcs work?

well gotta upgrade my memory I guess :D, thank you very much

Comment: you don't need to upgrade the PC. The cache can be cleared very easily if you need other data to be loaded. Chrome is just a very memory hungry software.

Answer (score -1):

If your running windows system its easy... Go to task manager, control alt delete u get your task manager Idk which windows your on but itll have a processes menu, thats all your background tasks, U may have a button see more or processes from all users. hit it. these are all your background tasks. If youde like to configure them while in task manager go to file click run "msconfig" no quotations, its just microsoft configuration. U get a boot configuration menu with all your services and startup programs u can disable all programs, services go to hide all microsoft check box do that and disable all... You can go through microsoft services and disable them but you need to know what ones. Lmk if it works good luck

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still 2gb use on startup that don't register

Comment: What kind of video card do you have, If its onboard I know it allocates the ram necessary to run it I dont think thats what it is but it could explain part of it. other than that the only thing I could think of is a damaged Ram stick, But usually when a stick is damaged itll give u beeping or youll get some kind of messups. have you did memory tests?